# Lint for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lint

Is there a lint utility for ASP.NET MVC? Given that I frequently specify views and links via strings, when I move things around or change entity names I often break things, which I then only find out about when something fails at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper's v6 (whose nightlies are now available, if you don't mind living on the edge) will catch this kind of error for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Refactor -> Rename and enable Search in Strings to replace every string in the solution

Answer (score 1):

Other option -- use the strongly typed helpers (which might still be in the futures assemblies). EG, `Html.Action<ProductsController>(x => x.ShowProduct(id))` ; really the only way to fly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there's something like that, but I'll tell you what I do: All my view names are in a struct that contains string constants. It's a pain to keep it sync'ed as the project changes, but it's worth it because you're far more likely to catch errors if you're using

```
ViewNames.Customer
```

rather than

```
"customer"
```